# How to create object (Object Repository) file in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am new into robot framework scripting. and I had question coming into mind, how I can create object repository into suite, where I kept all the object and call them into main script or any other robot file or i can manipulate objects programatically.

Below i had done in my suit -This is first file

```
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***
${FIRST_TAB}   xpath=//*[@id='ctl00_Header']
${Second_NEW}   xpath=//*[@id='ctl00_ContentOne']
.
.
.
```

I don't think this is standard approach. How I can manipulate above object when index is change or id is change dynamically. 
Did robot framework allow us to return locators as object into other file.
how I can prepare the object file and use it any where into the suite.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution is to create a resource file. Place all of your variables in that file, and then import that file into your test suite

The resource file might look like this:

```
# resources.robot
*** Variables ***
${FIRST_TAB}   xpath=//*[@id='ctl00_Header']
${Second_NEW}   xpath=//*[@id='ctl00_ContentOne']
```

You could then use it in a test suite like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Resource | resources.robot

*** Test Cases ***
| Example
| | log | First tab is ${FIRST_TAB}
```

For more information see [Resource and Variable Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Cheers For You. I will implement and let you know.